# xamarin - apply consistent navigation across all content page

Tags: xamarin, navigation, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am developing an APP using Xamarin, i trying to apply an consistent navigation system for my app.

I have used xamarin master detail navigation and binded the master page with few details page through ObservableCollection list.
My default details page is again a tabbled page. Within Tabled page on click of some button i need open some content page which are not part of master page.
What i want is- any conent page should open within the master page means from any content page master page's header and left sliding menu should be easily available to user.
I am tryng to bind master page from content page on runtime but no luck yet. Please help.

====updating my query for better understanding===

```
1. Sample master details page look like below
```

[[image: sample master detail page is look like below][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASl6f.png)

Click on item 1 open page 1 with sliding icon on left side of page title

[image]

Click on "GO TO PAGE 3" open page 3 with navigation back button. I think as this page is not bind to master page it shows normal back button. Basically i want to replace this navigation back button with "master detail" sliding button in every page those are not part of master page.

Please let me know how to replace navigation back button icon and behavior with master detail sliding button. I know following line of code can be used to open sliding menu but do not know how to hook the back button even.

(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = true;

[image]

Comment: Are you using some kind of MVVM framework? Frameworks like FreshMvvm have all sorts of standardized navigation functionality built-in.

Comment: @Steven- i'am not using any MVVM framwork. I'am new to mobile developement, can it be achieved only using xamarin master-details navigation

Comment: You will have to share some code and describe your test case. I don't see any problem loading any content page under your tabbed page because your tabbed page is detail page and you can specify any content page within it.